# After "cancel" click on Twitter, request token for the page is invalid (Twitter4j)

Tags: java, android, twitter

I am using Twitter4j to let my user's sign in to their Twitter account. They are able to successfully log in and out, but a problem occurs if they hit "cancel" on the Twitter popup dialog and go back to the app and then reopen the login, the login gives an error saying the request token for the page is invalid. I know I have the right consumer/secret keys because the login works if I don't click cancel and log in normally. Any ideas?

[image]

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

SharedPreferences pref;

private static String CONSUMER_KEY = "mykey";
private static String CONSUMER_SECRET = "mykey";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pref = getPreferences(0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
    edit.putString("CONSUMER_KEY", CONSUMER_KEY);
    edit.putString("CONSUMER_SECRET", CONSUMER_SECRET);
    edit.commit();

    Fragment login = new LoginFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, login);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}

}
```

**LoginFragment**

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
ImageView login;
Twitter twitter;
RequestToken requestToken = null;
AccessToken accessToken;
String oauth_url, oauth_verifier, profile_url;
Dialog auth_dialog;
WebView web;
SharedPreferences pref;
ProgressDialog progress;
Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
    login = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.login);
    pref = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
    twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(pref.getString("CONSUMER_KEY", ""),
            pref.getString("CONSUMER_SECRET", ""));

    login.setOnClickListener(new LoginProcess());
    return view;
}

private class LoginProcess implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new TokenGet().execute();

    }
}

private class TokenGet extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        try {
            requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
            oauth_url = requestToken.getAuthorizationURL()
                    + "&force_login=true";
            Log.d("URL", oauth_url);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return oauth_url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String oauth_url) {
        if (oauth_url != null) {
            Log.e("URL", oauth_url);
            auth_dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
            auth_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            auth_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.auth_dialog);
            web = (WebView) auth_dialog.findViewById(R.id.webv);
            web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            web.loadUrl(oauth_url);
            web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                boolean authComplete = false;

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                        Bitmap favicon) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    if (url.contains("oauth_verifier")
                            && authComplete == false) {
                        authComplete = true;
                        Log.e("Url", url);
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                        oauth_verifier = uri
                                .getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");

                        auth_dialog.dismiss();
                        new AccessTokenGet().execute();
                    } else if (url.contains("denied")) {
                        auth_dialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Sorry !, Permission Denied",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });
            auth_dialog.show();
            auth_dialog.setCancelable(true);

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Sorry !, Network Error or Invalid Credentials",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}

private class AccessTokenGet extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progress.setMessage("Fetching Data ...");
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        progress.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {

        try {

            accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken,
                    oauth_verifier);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
            edit.putString("ACCESS_TOKEN", accessToken.getToken());
            edit.putString("ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET",
                    accessToken.getTokenSecret());
            User user = twitter.showUser(accessToken.getUserId());
            profile_url = user.getOriginalProfileImageURL();
            edit.putString("NAME", user.getName());
            edit.putString("IMAGE_URL", user.getOriginalProfileImageURL());

            edit.commit();

        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean response) {
        if (response) {
            progress.hide();
            Fragment profile = new ProfileFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, profile);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();

        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an onCancelListener for the dialog and within that set the OAuthAccessToken to null.

```
mAuth_dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {       
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        sTwitter.setOAuthAccessToken(null);
    }
});
```